# Ajax - jQuery + HTML form -- Can't display selected option from form once submitted

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Trying to practice AJAX with forms.

I'm not sure if I'm setting this right.

What I'm trying to do is, when you hit submit, there will be a message saying "the number you chose is #" -- whatever number you chose from the dropdown.

When I click submit though, it opens up an error page... so obviously something is wrong. Not sure if a function is necessary either? I'm basically trying to replicate a scenario from CodeSchool :)

https://jsfiddle.net/zjtbf64p/4/

edit: thanks in advance!

```
******HTML*******
<form action="/echo/html" method="POST">
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<div></div>


******JAVASCRIPT*******
function test() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
      $.ajax('/echo/html/', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
          $('div').html('you chose ' + result);
       }
    });
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  test();
});
```

Comment: Consider editing your title to better fit your question. [Should questions include tags in their titles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)

Comment: i changed the title, sorry about that. hope that's clearer now

Answer (score 1):

Do you not need an extension (.php) after the test? - also is that the correct path for that - if its in the same directory  yuo will not need the "/" character.

```
$.ajax('/test.php',...
```

Also - assuming that you will have other forms and divs - best to identify each via id, class or name to target them correctly, and don't forget to put names on your input elements otherwise they will not be accessible as form elements.

```
******HTML*******
<form name="testForm" action="/test.php" method="POST">
  <select name="testSelect">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="testDiv"></div>


******JAVASCRIPT*******

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name=testform]').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
      $.ajax('/test.php', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
          $('#testDiv').html('you chose ' + result);
          }
        });
     });
});
```

Comment: my mistake! ill update my code. i changed the path to /echo/html/, after googling on how to do ajax in jsfiddle. but now i can't get the number i submitted to show up... --- edit: will work on the IDs as well, thanks. will update you on that

Comment: also - not sure you need the test() called  at the bottom - I just removed the function test(){} and wrapped in the document.ready() and it will work.

Comment: hey i used your code im still  getting the same result where once submitted, it only says "you chose" but it doesn't say which number I chose. i had to change the path to /echo/html

Comment: this will still be the wrong path - you need to configure your form to send the data to a page (usually a .php page that can do stuff with your passed variables) that will then return content back to you and that you can then put into the success call. This page will need to be able to receive the $_POST super global array (hence the .php extension) and do stuff - then you echo or return the outcome and that is what is passed back as the returned data to be inserted into your div.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle is working as intended!  Here's what's happening.

1. Javascript is hooking onto your form, and on submit, preventing it from doing what it normally does (forward you to the URL in `action=` with the form fields as data)
2. A user hits the submit button in your form
3. The form does not submit as normal, but your javascript takes over.
4. Your javascript sends an AJAX request to `/test` - which is taken from the javascript, NOT the form field `action=`.
5. The server at jsfiddle tries to serve up the content of `/test`, which they have configured to send back an error
6. Your javascript receives the contents of that error and looks for something to do with it.  You haven't configured an error object, so it discards the error.

Try editing your function `test()` to the following:

```
function test() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
      $.ajax('/test', {
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
          $('div').html('you chose ' + result);
       },
       error: function(result) {
            alert("an error!");
       }
    });
  });
};
```

You'll see that you're getting back an error from jsfiddle.

In your actual environment, what you need is a server side script to do something with.  If you sent your AJAX request to `test.php`, the code will pass the form variables to test.php hosted on your server, test.php will do something with those variables and return content.

Remember that AJAX is a way to communicate to a server and not just update parts of your page.  You take information, send it to a server script, that server script does something with that information, sends modified data back to the browser, and then you do something with that data.

Comment: hey there! thanks for the detailed feedback. this is what i need. so i noticed that the path i had was wrong. i thought you could put anything there (stupid me). so I googled how to do ajax on jsfiddle, and the proper path is /echo/html. now when I hit submit, i get a message saying "you chose ", but the number isn't displayed.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zjtbf64p/4/ -- will need to update the path to /test.php per the previous commenter above

Comment: The next problem you're going to run into is the data you're sending.  In your ajax options, you're calling `serialize()` on the variable `form`.  The problem is that the variable `form` has not been set.  I'd recommend taking a closer look at the tutorial you're using, or following another tutorial.  JSFiddle actually set up an example here: [JSFiddle AJAX example](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/yVbYQ/)